# Jquery tablesorder plugin not showing next/prev page buttons

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

so i have a table like this

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="results" style="direction:rtl;">
    <thead>
    <tr><td>شماره</td><td>شماره اختصاصی</td><td>نام فرستده</td><td>تاریخ ارسال</td><td>وضعیت انتشار</td><td>نمایش</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1231</td>
        <td>31311010119</td>
        <td>sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf</td>
        <td>1400/3/17</td>
        <td><span style="color:red;">test</span></td>
        <td><button data-content="test
 test
 test" style="width:100%;" id="display_post_contect" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">display</button></td>
    </tr>
        <td>1053</td>
        continues ....
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1054</td>
        continues ....
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and i have included both tablesorter and tablesorterpager inside **$(document).ready()**

```
<script src="<?php echo $js_dir; ?>jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $js_dir; ?>jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
```

this is how im using the plugin inside jquery

```
$('table.table').tablesorter();
        $('table.table').tablesorterPager();
```

and it does work meaning when the html table with about 300 rows loads in page the pager plugin only displays the **first 10 rows** but there is no next/prev buttons being displayed above or below the table
what am i missing here ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Should work.

See the full example with all parameters here: https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-pager.html

```js
$("table").tablesorter();
```

and then

```js
var pagerOptions = {
    // starting page of the pager (zero based index)
    page: 1,

    // Number of visible rows - default is 10
    size: 100,
}

$("table").tablesorterPager(pagerOptions);
```

So you should get 100 per Page - 10 is the default value.

Comment: tried it, didn't work. its inside the WordPress dashboard so im guessing there is some problem with WordPress ...

Comment: Yes this can be. Did you program a dashboard widget for this?

Comment: hey, sorry for the late reply. I switched to bootstrap datatables and it worked... for some reason tablesorterPager was not working inside wordpress dashboard